# pfSense - Prioritizing LAN Devices without ALTQ

Tags: pfsense

Without having [ALTQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALTQ) capabilities, are there any other ways, within [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/), that I can prioritize particular computers on the LAN?

**Some Details:**

Today, all of the computers on our network had almost no internet. I did a ping test to 1.1.1.1 and it looked like this:

```
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=128 ttl=51 time=13668 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=141 ttl=51 time=2290 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=142 ttl=51 time=2030 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=143 ttl=51 time=6841 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=144 ttl=51 time=5973 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=150 ttl=51 time=203 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=152 ttl=51 time=210 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=153 ttl=51 time=492 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=157 ttl=51 time=409 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=158 ttl=51 time=590 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=160 ttl=51 time=4532 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=165 ttl=51 time=4496 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=169 ttl=51 time=7024 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=170 ttl=51 time=6079 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=176 ttl=51 time=18830 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=178 ttl=51 time=17255 ms
```

After unplugging a particular computer from the network, the ping started looking like this:

```
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=214 ttl=51 time=46.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=215 ttl=51 time=45.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=216 ttl=51 time=40.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=217 ttl=51 time=40.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=218 ttl=51 time=39.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=219 ttl=51 time=47.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=220 ttl=51 time=41.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=221 ttl=51 time=40.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=222 ttl=51 time=43.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=223 ttl=51 time=40.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=224 ttl=51 time=40.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=225 ttl=51 time=46.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=226 ttl=51 time=41.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=227 ttl=51 time=44.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=228 ttl=51 time=42.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=229 ttl=51 time=46.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=230 ttl=51 time=48.3 ms
```

That computer is my child's gaming computer, and he wasn't knowingly doing anything on the internet. I'll be figuring out what that computer is doing later.

However, prior to doing that, I'd like to configure pfSense in a manner where, even if his computer is indeed trying to consume every bit of our ADSL's bandwidth, the firewall will give it such low priority, that it cannot accomplish this.

My goal is to give all our various voip traffic top priority. Secondly, I want to give the two work computers in the house the next highest priority, and last I want to give this Windows 10 gaming computer lowest priority.

Unfortunately, I must have made a poor choice on selecting the network adapters for our LANs. Because when I try to run the traffic shaping wizard, it tells me:

> This firewall does not have any LAN-type interfaces assigned that are
> capable of using ALTQ traffic shaping.

[image]

I have pfSense running on an intel nuc, which natively only has one network adapter that I'm using for WAN. The other two LAN ports are be facilitated by [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D8XTOD0):
[image]

I probably need to purchase a different device to accomplish my goals. Are there any ways, within pfSense, that I can prioritize particular computers on the LAN without having [ALTQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALTQ) capabilities?

Comment: I'm currently trying to find specs on the USB32000SPT to see what their official stance is on whether or not it supports [ALTQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALTQ). pfSense is based on UNIX; it may be that the USB32000SPT supports ALTQ, but the unix kernel doesn't know how to utilize it. I'm not sure yet. All I know right now, is that ALTQ is certainly not plug-and-play for pfSense if the USB32000SPT does indeed have that capability.

Comment: an interesting 'side' question is what chip that uses and if you can 'check' from freebsd or linux. There's about 2-3 companies that make these actual chips

Comment: I tried replacing that dual USB Ethernet adapter with two separate USB ethernet adapters, but I'm still getting the same issue that they don't support ALTQ (according to pfSense) when trying to do traffic shaping. Now I'm looking for some type of compatibly list to see if there are any USB ethernet adapters that will not only work with pfSense, but will also do ALTQ, so I can have traffic shaping too. These very same adapters did traffic shaping when I used them with [Zental](https://zentyal.com/community/) being the firewall.

Comment: I reading about [limiters](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/trafficshaper/limiters.html). This may be a way I can accomplish traffic shaping on pfSense without ALTQ capable network adapters.

Comment: Its a bit niche, so no promises but what to buy would be on topic on hardware recommendations stack exchange

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Thanks, I posted a hardware recommendation request [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16214/).